# Trying to understand why binding to a nested viewmodel fails

Tags: knockout.js

I have two ViewModels (although I like to think of the 'Person' ViewModel as the Model):

```
function Person() {
    var self = this;
    self.firstName = ko.observable("");
    self.lastName = ko.observable("");
}


function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.admin = ko.observable(null);
    self.something = ko.observable("Hello World");
}
```

And then I set AppViewModel.admin to an instance of Person:

```
var viewModel = new AppViewModel();

var bob = new Person();
bob.firstName("Sponge");
bob.lastName("Bob");
viewModel.admin(bob);

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

I then try to bind to it like this:

```
<p><strong data-bind="text: admin.firstName"></strong></p>
<p><strong data-bind="text: admin.lastName"></strong></p>
<p><strong data-bind="text: something"></strong></p>
```

I expected the output of this to be:

> **Sponge**
>   **Bob**
>   **Hello World**

However that is not the case, instead the output is simply "Hello World"
(Obviously 'something' is just an observable of the AppViewModel, so that part works)

Can someone explain why it doesn't work and what I should be doing instead?

The full example on jsFiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/XRPAH/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"admin" is an observable, so you need to "invoke it" to access the contained value:

```
<p><strong data-bind="text: admin().firstName"></strong></p>
```

Actually, if you do

```
data-bind="text: something"
```

this is just shorthand for

```
data-bind="text: something()"
```

But if the observable is part of an expression such as `admin.firstName`, you need to explicitly write down the parentheses.

Comment: Ah... of course. Did not realize you have to use them in the binding as well (or even think about doing it). Sometimes it's really in the details. *facepalm* Thank you! Saved me a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

your object `admin` is observable so you need to access it using `()`

for example :

```
<p><strong data-bind="text: admin().firstName"></strong></p>
```

and the same in the first line of your html it should be something like this

```
<p><strong data-bind="text: admin().firstName() + ' '+ admin().lastName()"></strong>
</p>
```

kindly check this **[Working Demo](http://fiddle.jshell.net/XRPAH/3/)**

Comment: Thnx, you answer came in just after Niko, but still thank you :)